# Python regular expression matching a multiline block of text but not replacing it

Tags: python, regex, replace, multiline

Ok so i have this piece of code:

```
def findNReplaceRegExp(file_name, regexp, replaceString, verbose=True, confirmationNeeded=True):
'''Replaces the oldString with the replaceString in the file given,\
   returns the number of replaces
'''
    # initialize local variables
    cregexp = re.compile(regexp, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    somethingReplaced = True
    ocurrences = 0
    isAborted = False

    # open file for read
    file_in = open(file_name, 'r')
    file_in_string = file_in.read()
    file_in.close()

    while somethingReplaced:
        somethingReplaced = False
        # if the regexp is found
        if cregexp.search(file_in_string):
            # make the substitution
            replaced_text = re.sub(regexp, replaceString, file_in_string)
            if verbose == True:
                # calculate the segment of text in which the resolution will be done

                # print the old string and the new string
                print '- ' + file_in_string
                print '+ ' + replaced_text
                if confirmationNeeded:
                    # ask user if this should be done
                    question = raw_input('Accept changes? [Yes (Y), No (n), Abort (a)] ')
                    question = string.lower(question)
                    if question == 'a':
                        isAborted = True
                        print "Aborted"
                        break
                    elif question == 'n':
                        pass
                    else:
                        file_in_string = replaced_text
                        somethingReplaced = True
                        ocurrences = ocurrences + 1
            else:
                file_in_string = replaced_text
                somethingReplaced = True
                ocurrences = ocurrences + 1

    # if some text was replaced, overwrite the original file
    if ocurrences > 0 and not isAborted:
        # open the file for overwritting
        file_out = open(file_name, 'w')
        file_out.write(file_in_string)
        file_out.close()
        if verbose: print "File " + file_name + " written"
```

And this file

```
CMC_SRS T10-24400: DKU Data Supply: SN Time Break-In Area
CMC_SRS T10-24401: DKU Data Supply: SN Transponder Enable Area
CMC_SRS T10-24402: DKU Data Supply: SN Adjust Master Slave Area
CMC_SRS T10-24403: DKU Data Supply: SN ATEC Area
CMC_SRS T10-24404: DKU Data Supply: SN PTEC Area
CMC_SRS T10-25449: DKU Data Supply: SN Self Init Area
CMC_SRS T10-24545: DKU Data Supply: SN Time Area
CMC_SRS T10-4017: RFI display update
CMC_SRS T10-6711: Radio Interface to PLS Equipment
CMC_SRS T10-21077: Safety Requirements: Limit FM Power
```

When i call the procedure with this file and these parameters:
regexp=24403.*24404
replace=TESTSTRING

i get a coincidence (it matches and questions what to do) but when its time to replace nothing happens... Whats wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're finding with `cregexp`, which has the multiline option set, but then replacing with `regexp`, which may or may not.

Comment: And you could just replace `regexp` with `cregexp` because re.sub accepts a string as well as a regex object as its first parameter.